# cpp|7|error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(int&, int&, int&)'|

Tags: c++11

****`I am new to programming, and unable to understand the following problem

So Can anyone explain me how to fix the error. It is just a simple program to calculate second greatest`****

---

This is the error code
s PC\Documents\n1\2.cpp|7|error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string::basic_string(int&, int&, int&)'|

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int num1, num2, num3;


string SecondGreatest(num1, num2, num3){

    string answer1;

 if(num1 > num2)
{
    if(num2 > num3)
{

        answer1 = "Num 2";
    }
    else
{

        answer1 = "Num 3";
    }
}
else if(num2 < num1)
{
    if(num1 > num3)
{

        answer1 = "Num 1";
    }else
{

    answer1 = "Num 3";
    }
}
else if(num3 > num2)
{
    if(num2 > num1)
{

        answer1 = "Num 2";
    }else
{

        answer1 = "Num 1";
    }
}
else if(num3 > num1)
{
    if(num1 > num2)
{

        answer1 = "Num 1";
    }else
{

    answer1 = "Num 2";
    }
}
 return answer1;
 }

//main function
 int main(){

     cout << "Write any three numbers" << endl;
     cin >> num1;
     cin >> num2;
     cin >> num3;
//outputting the second greatest function
 cout << SecondGreatest(num1, num2, num3) << endl;



 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Try changing `string SecondGreatest(num1, num2, num3)` to `string SecondGreatest(int num1, int num2, int num3)` and you should not use the same names for your arguments and global variables and `num1`, `num2` and `num3` don't need to be global.

Comment: Also, I don't think the `<<` operator for `cout` has an overload for `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as written below and consider the hints given as comments in the fixed code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>     // Don't forget to include std::string header
using namespace std;  // OK for small code examples, but should be avoided in any real C++ code

int num1, num2, num3; // No need to define this in global scope. Could be moved to the main function.

string SecondGreatest(int num1, int num2, int num3) // Variable type required for each parameter, here int
{
    // Please care about the indentation. It makes your code better readable.
    // Logic improved to get always the second greatest number given.
    // num1 is the greatest number, now let us find the second greatest.
    if(num1 > num2 && num1 > num3 && num2 != num3)
    {
        if(num2 > num3)
        {
            return "Num 2";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Num 3";
        }
    }
    // num2 is the greatest number, now let us find the second greatest.
    else if(num2 > num1 && num2 > num3 && num1 != num3)
    {
        if(num1 > num3)
        {
            return "Num 1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Num 3";
        }
    }
    // num3 is the greatest number, now let us find the second greatest.
    else if(num3 > num1 && num3 > num2 && num1 != num2)
    {
        if(num2 > num1)
        {
            return "Num 2";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Num 1";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Some or all of the given numbers are equal.";
    }
}

//main function
int main()
{
    cout << "Write any three numbers" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    cin >> num3;
    //outputting the second greatest function
    cout << SecondGreatest(num1, num2, num3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tested with Visual Studio 2019, hence with Visual C++ 2019 compiler.

Your error might occur, because the parameter type `int` is missing in your definition of function `SecondGreatest(...)`. But also the `string` header has to be included to make your program run.

Please care also about the logic to find the second greatest number of given three and handle the code indentation properly as it makes the code much more readable.